# Display the image after uploading it from another php file through ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When the page is loaded, the image specified in src is displayed.When a user clicks on the form to upload the image,everything works fine except the image on the page does not change.
It is because when the user clicks on the form to upload the image, he is directed to php file 2 but from there there is no request to change the image in php file 1. How can I achieve this (using ajax and jquery)?

Comment: You want to display Image that User uploaded after Form Submit?

Comment: Yes..the image is uploaded in php file2 but I have to display image in php file1.

Comment: Just send the src of new image from php file 2 and then change src of image tab to this new src using jquery. $('id_of_img tag').attr('src','new_src');

Comment: @user3452721 u have to echo that new src in php file 2 to have it in success function as parameter.

Comment: It works on chrome sometimes but not on firefox.Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. This is the core.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#imgInp').on('change', function() {
            readPath(this);
            });
            });

            function readPath(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<form id="form1">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" width="500px" height="200px" alt="your image" />
</form>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Where in JS file should I write it?Secondly, the thing is that actually I want to call the div with id="image_container" again so as not to show the new src file name and path... using ajax without reloading webpage.Any ideas?

Comment: In an ajax call,What you echo in the the php file is what you get returned as data there. I will show you a full example shortly.

Comment: I have added a new code, and omitted ajax since jquery have some security issues giving the path of uploaded file. Try new code

Comment: What conditions do you want to check. Also when do you want to check? At the time the file is uploaded or when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another code snippet. Check your conditions in the server part and don't forget provide the locations correctly in server side and image src.

**HTML Part**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<style>
form { display: block; margin: 20px auto; background: #eee; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px }
#progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
#bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
#percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Ajax File Upload Demo</h1>
 <img id="blah" src="#" width="500px" height="200px" alt="your image" />
<form id="myForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" size="60" name="myfile">
     <input type="submit" value="Ajax File Upload">
 </form>

 <div id="progress">
        <div id="bar"></div>
        <div id="percent">0%</div >
</div>
<br/>

<div id="message"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var options = { 
    beforeSend: function() 
    {
        $("#progress").show();
        //clear everything
        $("#bar").width('0%');
        $("#message").html("");
        $("#percent").html("0%");
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
    {
        $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
        $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');

    },
    success: function() 
    {
        $("#bar").width('100%');
        $("#percent").html('100%');

    },
    complete: function(response) 
    {
        $("#blah").attr("src",response.responseText);
    },
    error: function()
    {
        $("#message").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");

    }

}; 

     $("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);

});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Upload.php**

```
<?php
//upload.php
$output_dir = "C:/wamp/www/";

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
    //Filter the file types , if you want.
    if ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"] > 0)
    {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        //move the uploaded file to uploads folder;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);

     echo $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: You can check the conditions in upload.php using $_FILES["file"]["size"] and $_FILES["file"]["type"]

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working on firefox.Though the page does not reload but the newer image also does not get displayed until I manually reload the page.